# Ref with custom class - reactdate picker

Tags: reactjs, ref, reactstrap

I am trying to set focus on react datepicker when enter is pressed on earlier component(input filed).
I read a official documentation, and example with simple  field is worked, but when I change  with DatePicker I get a old error

```
TypeError: this.inputAccountDate.focus is not a function
```

My function is:

```
function CustomDatePicker(props) {
return (
    <div>
        {/* <input ref={props.innerRef} /> */}
            <DatePicker className="form-control" 
                placeholderText="Izaberite datum"
                dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
                maxDate={new Date()}
                ref={props.innerRef}
        />
    </div>
);
```

}

And snippet code from class with form is:

```
     <Col className="pr-md-1" md="3">
        <FormGroup >
          <label>Datum računa</label>
           <div>
               <CustomDatePicker
                  innerRef={(input) => { this.inputAccountDate = input }}
                  />
           </div>
          </FormGroup>
      </Col>
```

Component where I call a function to set focus is

```
 <Col className="pr-md-1" md="3">
   <FormGroup>
      <label>Broj računa</label>
      <Input style={{'borderColor':'lightgray', 'fontSize':'14px'}}
         innerRef={(input) => { this.inputAccountNumber = input }}
         onKeyDown={this.focusAccountDate}
         placeholder="Br.računa"
         type="text"
         value={this.state.accountNumber || (header === null ? "" : 
             header.account_number) }
         onChange={this.changeAccountNumber}
         onFocus={(e)=>e.target.select()}
         required
        />
       </FormGroup>
    </Col>
```

Function which managing a focus is

```
    focusAccountDate = (e) => {
    if(e !== undefined) {
        if(e.key === 'Enter') {
            this.inputAccountDate.focus()
        }
    }
}
```

and inputAccountDate is `this.inputAccountDate = React.createRef()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `setFocus()` instead of `focus`. There is no `focus` in `DatePicker`
2. In functional Component, the passing ref reference with props is not a valid way.
   You need to know [Forwarding Ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)

Your CustomDatePicker should be changed like the following.

```
function CustomDatePicker(props, ref) {
  return (
    <div>
            <DatePicker className="form-control" 
                placeholderText="Izaberite datum"
                dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
                maxDate={new Date()}
                ref={ref}
        />
    </div>
  );
}

export default React.forwardRef(CustomDatePicker)
```

Comment: what else do I need to change, do you have some instructions?

Comment: @Qli Then, it can be a timing issue. Did you call your function immediately at mounting?

Comment: Can you call `ref={(input) => { input.focus()}}`

Comment: I edited my answer, I added a code where I call a function to set focus

Comment: @Qli Is there function name `focus` in `DatePicker`??? It seems to `setFocus` in code...

https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/blob/be3dd7a61fc2e4cc2927af05e8693ed0e20805ee/src/index.jsx#L343

Comment: As far as i know there is no function called focus in datapicker

Comment: @Qli then what is `onKeyDown={inputAccountNumber}` ??..

Comment: I edited my answer... onKeyDown i call a function witch set focus on DatePicker, called focusAccountDate

Comment: That is problem.. There is no `focus` in `DatePicker` ref object. use `setFocus` !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217963/discussion-between-qli-and-mj-studio).